# How to increase performance of this code

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I try to reduce the time use for this code.
My code is to calculate exponential moving average(as ema(data,period) function) of 2500 stocks.

```
input::   stock_data[name] = [x,x,x....] 
output::  ema[stockname][period] = [x,x,x....]
```

my code:

```
stock_names = ['ABC',...] #2500 name
ema_periods = [5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 75, 90, 100, 200] #19 periods

# get data
stock_data = dict()
for name in stock_names:
    stock_data[name] = get_stock_data(name) #each name keep 2000 values

start = time.time()
ema_dict = dict((key, dict((period, ema(stock_data[key], period)) for period in ema_periods)) for key in stock_data.keys())
print('elasped : ', time.time()-start)
```

I have run it 10 times

AVG. Time elasped = 17.60 sec

I want suggestion to improve my performance only at

```
ema_dict = dict((key, dict((period, ema(stock_data[key], period)) for period in ema_periods)) for key in stock_data.keys())
```

because of the data is mocked data does it have better way.

Thank you.

Comment: I think the performance bottleneck is probably not with this code, but with `get_stock_data(..)` or `ema(..)`.

Comment: What is `get_stock_data` and `ema`?

Answer (score 0):

As comments stated, we don't have access to all the routines, but things can still be sped up here.

- using dict comprehension instead of generator comprehension issuing tuples to feed to dict. Creating a `tuple` costs time. You have 2 nested potential dict comps here.
- not accessing `stock_data` dictionary each time by key. You can iterate by key and value

my proposal:

```
ema_dict = {key : {period: ema(value, period) for period in ema_periods} for key,value in stock_data.items()}
```

And following the same principle, the first init loop could be written like this:

```
stock_data = {name:get_stock_data(name) for name in stock_names}
```